# Animate position of UITableView without scrolling table

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Trying to achieve a simple transition sort of thing here, and a bit stuck on how to do it.

I have a view with a table, and some info above it, looks like this:

[image: image one]

Now I want to be able to scroll the table view, and have it move the info and photo sections up as it scroll. I can achieve this by editing the `constant` of the `photo.topAnchor`. However this makes the finger scroll both the table, and move it up, giving the impression to the user that it's scrolling faster than they're scrolling (like it's slipping).

Anyone got a better idea of how this should be done?

Comment: It might be better for you to embed the Photo and Info into `UIScrollView` and move  `UiScrollView` simultaneously when user scrolls in `UITableView`

Comment: Do you want the Photo and Info to sidle up and out of view? Or do you want it to change shape (like a parallax effect)? If you only need it to slide up and away, make it the table view's `.tableHeaderView`

Answer (score 0):

I did notice a while ago that the official youtube app does the same what you described, and I thought that there is no better way. But I ended up with using the tableHeaderView (not the same as the tableView’s headers! These are two different things).

Additional info, that probably doesn’t count for you:
If you want to animate the height of the tableHeaderView that can be a little tricky but I can highlight that it’s definitely solvable. And if there are some hidden requirements of your problem, then of course this might / might not help. Although I cannot post code now, if you ended up using this solution I can help you out if you stuck (I know that SO can’t give a full answer about the “dirty side” of the tableHeaderView, I can relate since I read all posts about this tricky view before I managed to do the task).